# Custom flag textarea overflows at right

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, design

It seems that the otherText textarea which is meant for the custom text when flagging a question "other (needs ♦ moderator attention)" is overflowing the right side of the containing box.

[image]

It overflows even when the textarea is blank.

[image]

My system is Chromium 40.0.2214.91, Fedora 21, KDE desktop.

Comment: That was apparently status completed in January @David, so this is a regression and can't be a dupe (though it may be worth pinging Nick on his answer there)

Comment: @Ben One of the comments said it wasn't fixed for Chrome "The 'fix' has not fixed the bug for me, on the latest Chrome on Windows 7 Professional x64" so it could still be an issue for Chrome. Will ping nick.

Comment: I was just about reporting this... BTW, can repro on Firefox 31 ESR.

Comment: Interesting, no-repro on Chromium 42 and Opera 27 on Windows 7 x64. Has this been fixed in the last 12 hours?

Comment: afaik Firefox *still* requires `-moz-` prefix on `box-sizing:border-box` - just looking at it I would guess it has `width:100%` and the padding/border is making it overflow.

Comment: @Niet: [Firefox understands `box-sizing` just fine.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) It's kind of a red herring, though, since there's no `box-sizing` in the stylesheet for that textarea. In fact, the real problem is that *there's no `width` either*, so the textarea just defaults to 80 columns wide, or whatever that happens to be for the font being used. The old stylesheet had `width: 575px` (which looks slightly too narrow to me; I'd prefer 600px), but it seems to have been lost in the redesign.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Well it's about time... Thanks for updating me on that :)